# Docker Compose how to extend service with build to use an image instead

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Having a base `docker-compose.yml` like the following:

```
version: '2'
services:
  web:
    build: .
...
```

How can I extend it to use an image instead?

`docker-compose.prod.yml`

```
version: '2'
services:
  web:
    image: username/repo:tag
```

Running it with docker `docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml -f docker-compose.prod.yml up` still promps:

> Building web 
>   Step 1/x : FROM ...

I tried with `docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml -f docker-compose.prod.yml up --no-build`:

> ERROR: Service 'web' needs to be built, but --no-build was passed.

I'm expecting the "Pulling from name/repo message" instead. Which options do I have? Or do I need to create a complete duplicate file to handle this slight modification?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Omit the `build` on the base `docker-compose.yml`, and place it in a `docker-compose.override.yml` file.

> When you run docker-compose up it reads the overrides automatically.

Extracted from the [Docker Compose Documentation](https://docs.docker.com/compose/extends/#example-use-case).

Since your **`docker-compose.yml`** file must have either build or image, we'll use image that has less priority, resulting in:

```
version: '2'
services:
  web:
    image: repo
[...]
```

Now let's move onto **`docker-compose.override.yml`**, the one that will run by default (meaning `docker-compose up` or `docker-compose run web command`).

By default we want it to build the image from our `Dockerfile`, so we can do this simply by using `build: .`

```
version: '2'
services:
  web:
    build: .
```

The production one **`docker-compose.prod.yml`** run by using `docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml -f docker-compose.prod.yml up` will be similar to this one, excepting that in this case we want it to take the image from the Docker repository:

```
version: '2'
services:
  web:
    image: repo
```

Since we already have the same `image: repo` on our base `docker-compose.yml` file we can omit it here (but that's completely optional).

Answer (score 1):

To use build instead image in `docker-compose.override.yml` you should replace image with local image name and then build this image with target.

In `docker-compose.override.yml`:

```
    image: username-repo-tag
    build:
      context: .
      target: username-repo-tag
```

In your `Dockerfile` you should add target to `FROM` tag:

```
FROM username/repo:tag as username-repo-tag
...
your instructions
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem, i solved it in an other way. I find this the simple way:

```
version: "3"
services:
  api-gateway:
    build:
      dockerfile: ./path/to/your/Dockerfile
```

Leaving this here, maybe it helps some one ^^

Answer (score 0):

In 04/2023, the compose spec has been extended with the [ability for override to reset value to null](https://github.com/compose-spec/compose-spec/pull/340). The example in the [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/13-merge/#reset-value) covers exactly this case. The resulting `docker-compose.prod.yml` would look like this:

```
version: '2'
services:
  web:
    build: !reset null
    image: username/repo:tag
```